# Non-factorization of partition functions in AdS/CFT

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, partition-function, ads-cft

I have seen this comment a lot in recent papers. This has to do with the AdS/CFT correspondence and Euclidean asymptotically AdS wormholes.

So when we calculate the partition function of two $D-1$ dimensional CFTs which are disconnected the partition functions factorize. I understand that this means that the partition function of each CFT is a disconnected diagram. Then in the gravity side (which is $D$ dimensional) when we do the same calculation we end up with a disconnected geometry plus a connected one.

My question is, what exactly do we mean by "the partition functions factorize"? In mathematical terms is it that
$$
Z_{\text{full}}= \langle Z_1\rangle\langle Z_2\rangle
$$
but in the gravity side we have
$$
Z_{\text{full}}= \langle Z_1 Z_2\rangle
$$